# How can I make a dial pad interface?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I want to make an interface for phone calls and I can't find any library or even a sample project that implements a dial up interface, do you know any useful materials for creating a dial up interface?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Did you have a look at this? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: I have created a sample code without auto layout for the custom dial pad
See if this can help you.

https://github.com/Kadasiddha/dailPad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created a sample code without auto layout for the custom dial pad
See if this can help you.

https://github.com/Kadasiddha/dailPad

Answer (score -1):

i have done. you can check out from here  https://github.com/himesh1996/PhoneBook

Comment: Can you explain a bit about your solution?